# SAS to HIVE2 Cloudera - Error trying to write

Tags: hadoop, hive, sas

I have the following error while trying to write on the hive2 db :

```
ERROR: java.io.IOException: Could not get block locations. Source file "/tmp/sasdata-e1-...dlv - Aborting...block==null
```

the error appears when trying to write a new table or append rows to an existing table. I can connect correctly to the db (through a libname), read tables from the schema and when trying to create a new table the new table get created but empty because the error above happens .
Can someone help pls?

Thank you

Comment: Could you post the relevant logs sections from you hive log?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that hive is mostly just a metadatastore that helps you to read files from HDFS.  Yes, it does this through a database paradigm but it's really operating on HDFS.  Each table is created in an HDFS directory, and files are created.

This sounds like you don't have write permissions to the hdfs folder you are writing to. (but you have read)

To solve this problem you need to understand what user you are using and where the data is being written.

If you are creating a simple table you need to check if you can write to the hive warehouse directory.  If you are purposely creating files in a specific hDFS folder you should check that.
Here's a command to help you determine where the data is being written to.

```
show create table [mytable]
```

If it doesn't mention a HDFS location you need to find get permissions to the hive warehouse. (Typicallys located hdfs:/user/hive/warehouse  , but is actually defined in $HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-default.xml if it's located elsewhere).